# Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.I'm confused about creating trigger

Tags: sql, oracle

Create a sequence named SEQ_CUSTOMER and a trigger named TR_CUSTOMER_ID that will automatically generate a sequence of numbers for the C_ID column. This sequence should start at 10,000 and increment by 1.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "SEQ_CUSTOMER" 
   MINVALUE 50 MAXVALUE 999999999990
   INCREMENT BY 1 
   START WITH 10000; 

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TR_CUSTOMER_ID" 
BEFORE INSERT ON "CUSTOMERS" 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  SELECT "SEQ_CUSTOMER". NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.C_ID FROM DUAL; 
END;
```

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

```
SQL> SHOW ERRORS;
Errors for TRIGGER "TR_CUSTOMER_ID":

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
2/1      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
2/9      PL/SQL: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist
SQL>
```

How to fix the problem, thanks

Comment: Lose the double quotes from the sequence name. You probably have (mismatched) whitespaces in use.

Comment: like GurV wrote, you have spaces in your sequence name. Lose the quotes.

Comment: thanks, I remove the whitesapces

Answer (score 1):

is first

```
DROP SEQUENCE SEQ_CUSTOMER;
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_CUSTOMER START WITH 10000;
```

is second

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_CUSTOMER_ID
BEFORE INSERT
ON CUSTOMERS
REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.C_ID := SEQ_CUSTOMER.nextval;
END TR_CUSTOMER_ID;
```

Comment: A side note: In this case, there is no need in `REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old` Plus, the capability of assigning a sequence value to a variable is version dependent and OP didn't say what version of RDBMS he/she's using.

Comment: THANKS!!!! But I want to know that why do I need REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old here?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space from the trigger, also you can write them between the quotes.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "SEQ_CUSTOMER" 
   MINVALUE 50 MAXVALUE 999999999990
   INCREMENT BY 1 
   START WITH 10000
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TR_CUSTOMER_ID" 
BEFORE INSERT ON "CUSTOMERS" 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    SELECT SEQ_CUSTOMER.NEXTVAL
  INTO   :new.ID
  FROM   dual;
END;
/
```